# Confused about output with comparison operators is and == in this case

Tags: python

Say I have a list:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, nan, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why are these 2 outputs different?

```
for x in my_list:
    if x == np.nan:
        continue
    print(x, end= " ")
```

0 1 2 3 nan 5 6 7 8 9

```
for x in my_list:
    if x is np.nan:
        continue
    print(x, end= " ")
```

0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Check [differences between `is and ==`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-operator-python/)

Comment: It is because np.nan == np.nan yields false. It con not compare nan to nan

Comment: A very good article to clear your doubts: https://towardsdatascience.com/navigating-the-hell-of-nans-in-python-71b12558895b

Comment: Use `np.isnan(number)`

Comment: FWIW, the correct API for testing for `np.nan` is [np.isnan](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html?highlight=nan#numpy.isnan). - edit: ah, Patrick beat me to it, leaving for the direct link :).